# Having trouble understanding a section of my rental contract in Dutch

Tags: netherlands, rental, contracts, translations

I am about to rent house and I received the contract but I don't understand one of points even after translate it, so I hope someone explain this to me.

> Deze  overeenkomst  is  aangegaan  voor  een korte  duur met  inachtneming  van  het  feit  dat  de verhuurder  i.v.m.  privé  omstandigheden  tijdelijk  geen  behoefte  heeft  aan het  gehuurde  en deze derhalve  ook  tijdelijk  niet  kan gebruiken  voor huisvesting. Mede  ter  voorkoming  van brand, inbraak en  andere  schade  acht  de  verhuurder  het  wenselijk  het  gehuurde  tijdelijk  in gebruik te  geven aan  huurder. Huurder  verklaart  op  de  hoogte  te  zijn  van  deze  beperkte  gebruiksduur en  heeft  hiertegen geen  bezwaar  aangezien huurder  voornemens is het  gehuurde  uitsluitend  voor  de  onder  3.1. genoemde  periode  te  gebruiken i.v.m. behoefte  aan  tijdelijke  woonruimte  in  verband  met tijdelijke  werkzaamheden  in  Nederland  xxxx .  Huurder  is  zich  bewust  van het  feit  dat het  gehuurde  slechts  tijdelijk gehuurd  kan  worden  en dat  huurder  geholpen is met  deze  tijdelijke  oplossing. Na beëindiging  van  deze  huurovereenkomst  wordt  het gehuurde  terstond  in gebruik genomen door de  verhuurder  bestemd  voor bewoning. Huurder  verklaart het  gehuurde  aan  het  einde  van  de  huurovereenkomst  vrij  en  ontruimd  - behoudens de  aan verhuurder  toebehorende  roerende  goederen  welke  in  het  gehuurde waren bij aanvang  der huur  -  en schoongemaakt  ter  vrije beschikking  van  verhuurder  te stellen.  Indien  en voorzover verhuurder  aan  het  einde  van  de  huurovereenkomst  niet  de vrije beschikking  heeft  over  het  gehuurde  door welke  oorzaak  dan  ook,  verklaart  huurder  nu reeds  voor alsdan  aan verhuurder  een  terstond  opeisbare boete  te  zullen voldoen  van  € 226,89  per  dag  voor elke  dag  dat huurder  het  gehuurde  na het  einde  van  de huurovereenkomst  niet  ter  vrije  beschikking  geeft,  zonder  dat  enige  ingebrekestelling  door  verhuurder  van  huurder  vereist  is  en  onverminderd het  recht  van  verhuurder  om  vergoeding van  geleden schade,  kosten  en  interesten  te  vorderen  van  huurder. Op grond  van  artikel 7:232  lid  2  BW  zijn  de  afdeling  7.4.5  van  het  BW  (te  weten artikelen 233  tot  en met  282  van Boek  7BW)  niet  van  toepassing  op  deze  huurovereenkomst  als  mede  de  Uitvoeringswet huurprijzen woonruimte  zijn  op  deze  overeenkomst  niet  van  toepassing, daar  het  hier een overeenkomst  betreft, die  uitdrukkelijk naar  zijn  aard  van  korte  duur is.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part of this you don't understand?

Comment: @einpoklum all the text, did't get the idea of it, it mentioned dutch law rules also fines for what, I didn't get it ?!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The passage you quoted consists of two parts:

1. Terms regarding the fact of the rental being for a short rather than long term
2. Terms regarding the obligation to clear the property of stuff when the rental period ends. This includes an obligation to pay a daily amount if the property is not clear at the end of the contract period - as (supposedly) the landlord cannot again freely use it.

I think the [Google Translation](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Deze%20overeenkomst%20is%20aangegaan%20voor%20een%20korte%20duur%20met%20inachtneming%20van%20het%20feit%20dat%20de%20verhuurder%20i.v.m.%20priv%C3%A9%20omstandigheden%20tijdelijk%20geen%20behoefte%20heeft%20aan%20het%20gehuurde%20en%20deze%20derhalve%20ook%20tijdelijk%20niet%20kan%20gebruiken%20voor%20huisvesting.%20Mede%20ter%20voorkoming%20van%20brand%2C%20inbraak%20en%20andere%20schade%20acht%20de%20verhuurder%20het%20wenselijk%20het%20gehuurde%20tijdelijk%20in%20gebruik%20te%20geven%20aan%20huurder.%20Huurder%20verklaart%20op%20de%20hoogte%20te%20zijn%20van%20deze%20beperkte%20gebruiksduur%20en%20heeft%20hiertegen%20geen%20bezwaar%20aangezien%20huurder%20voornemens%20is%20het%20gehuurde%20uitsluitend%20voor%20de%20onder%203.1.%20genoemde%20periode%20te%20gebruiken%20i.v.m.%20behoefte%20aan%20tijdelijke%20woonruimte%20in%20verband%20met%20tijdelijke%20werkzaamheden%20in%20Nederland%20xxxx%20.%20Huurder%20is%20zich%20bewust%20van%20het%20feit%20dat%20het%20gehuurde%20slechts%20tijdelijk%20gehuurd%20kan%20worden%20en%20dat%20huurder%20geholpen%20is%20met%20deze%20tijdelijke%20oplossing.%20Na%20be%C3%ABindiging%20van%20deze%20huurovereenkomst%20wordt%20het%20gehuurde%20terstond%20in%20gebruik%20genomen%20door%20de%20verhuurder%20bestemd%20voor%20bewoning.%20Huurder%20verklaart%20het%20gehuurde%20aan%20het%20einde%20van%20de%20huurovereenkomst%20vrij%20en%20ontruimd%20-%20behoudens%20de%20aan%20verhuurder%20toebehorende%20roerende%20goederen%20welke%20in%20het%20gehuurde%20waren%20bij%20aanvang%20der%20huur%20-%20en%20schoongemaakt%20ter%20vrije%20beschikking%20van%20verhuurder%20te%20stellen.%20Indien%20en%20voorzover%20verhuurder%20aan%20het%20einde%20van%20de%20huurovereenkomst%20niet%20de%20vrije%20beschikking%20heeft%20over%20het%20gehuurde%20door%20welke%20oorzaak%20dan%20ook%2C%20verklaart%20huurder%20nu%20reeds%20voor%20alsdan%20aan%20verhuurder%20een%20terstond%20opeisbare%20boete%20te%20zullen%20voldoen%20van%20%E2%82%AC%20226%2C89%20per%20dag%20voor%20elke%20dag%20dat%20huurder%20het%20gehuurde%20na%20het%20einde%20van%20de%20huurovereenkomst%20niet%20ter%20vrije%20beschikking%20geeft%2C%20zonder%20dat%20enige%20ingebrekestelling%20door%20verhuurder%20van%20huurder%20vereist%20is%20en%20onverminderd%20het%20recht%20van%20verhuurder%20om%20vergoeding%20van%20geleden%20schade%2C%20kosten%20en%20interesten%20te%20vorderen%20van%20huurder.%20Op%20grond%20van%20artikel%207%3A232%20lid%202%20BW%20zijn%20de%20afdeling%207.4.5%20van%20het%20BW%20(te%20weten%20artikelen%20233%20tot%20en%20met%20282%20van%20Boek%207BW)%20niet%20van%20toepassing%20op%20deze%20huurovereenkomst%20als%20mede%20de%20Uitvoeringswet%20huurprijzen%20woonruimte%20zijn%20op%20deze%20overeenkomst%20niet%20van%20toepassing%2C%20daar%20het%20hier%20een%20overeenkomst%20betreft%2C%20die%20uitdrukkelijk%20naar%20zijn%20aard%20van%20korte%20duur%20is.) of the text is pretty clear...

Comment: @AhmedRagheb: See edit.

Comment: @ einpoklum thanks alot, so it not something i should worry about.

Comment: @AhmedRagheb: Laa shukr 3ala waajeb. Also, "It is not something i should worry about" - Well, not right now, but you will need to plan for not getting stuck with furniture in that place.

Comment: @AhmedRagheg: Something else -> new question, and make it very specific please :-)